# 2D wave equation solve using laplace transformation mathematica

Tags: wolfram-cloud

I'm trying to solve a wave equation using laplace and inverse laplace transformation .
But facing problem in inverse part.My problem and codes in the below:
[image]

```
eqn = D[T[x, t], {t, 2}] - D[T[x, t], {x, 2}] == 0
w[x_, t_] = D[T[x, t], t]

LaplaceTransform[eqn, t, s] /. {T[x, 0] -> Sin[\[Pi] x],w[x, 0] -> 3 x + 1} 


eqn2 = -2 - 3 x + s^2 tT[x, s] - D[tT[x, s], {x, 2}] - s Sin[Pi*x] == 0



f = tT[x, s] /.DSolve[{eqn2, tT[0, s] == 0, tT[1, s] == 5}, tT[x, s], x]

InverseLaplaceTransform[f, s, t]
```

Comment: I am not following this command **LaplaceTransform[eqn, t, s] /. {T[x, 0] -> Sin[\[Pi] x],w[x, 0] -> 3 x + 1}**  there is NO `w[x, 0]` in the output of the `LaplaceTransform` command. So what does this replacement supposed to do? And is it there?

Comment: w[x,0] is a boundary condition w[x_, t_] = D[T[x, t], t]==0 where t=0

Comment: oh, I see now you had defined it earlier.

Comment: You have lots of errors. `eqn2 = -2 - 3 x...` should be `eqn2 = -1 - 3 x..` and `tT[1, s] == 5` should be `tT[1, s] == 0`

Answer (score 2):

This gives same solution as Mathematica

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
eqn = D[T[x, t], {t, 2}] - D[T[x, t], {x, 2}] == 0
ic = {T[x, 0] == Sin[Pi*x], (D[T[x, t], t] /. t -> 0) == 3*x + 1}
bc = {T[0, t] == 0, T[1, t] == 0}
lap = LaplaceTransform[eqn, t, s] /. (ic /. Equal -> Rule)
lap = lap /. {LaplaceTransform[T[x, t], t, s] -> Y[s, x], 
   LaplaceTransform[Derivative[2, 0][T][x, t], t, s] -> 
    D[Y[s, x], {x, 2}]}
solY = DSolveValue[lap, Y[s, x], x]
eq1 = (solY /. x -> 0) == 0
eq2 = (solY /. x -> 1) == 0 // Simplify
solC = Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {C[1], C[2]}]
solY = solY /. solC // First
mysol = Simplify[InverseLaplaceTransform[solY, s, t]]
mysol = FullSimplify[mysol /. HeavisideTheta[_] -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: In the above `HeavisideTheta[_] -> 1` because it is 1 for all values, since $t>0$ and $0<x<1$.

Verify

```
sol = T -> Function[{x, t}, Evaluate@Activate@mysol];
eqn /. sol // Simplify
ic /. sol // Simplify
bc /. sol // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is the same as what Mathematica gives (but written different)

```
 mmaSol = DSolveValue[{eqn, ic, bc}, T[x, t], {x, t}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sol = T -> Function[{x, t}, Evaluate@Activate@mmaSol];
eqn /. sol // Simplify
ic /. sol // Simplify
bc /. sol // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]